# How to remove <span class="st">&#185;</span> in xml using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have XML code and a `<span class="st">&#185;</span>` tag inside `<desc>` is coming in, how I can remove this using XSLT code?
here is the input:

```
<features>
         <desc>
The sleek and slim OneRemote automatically detects and controls all compatible connected devices and content.<span class="st">&#185;</span>
         </desc>
         <imageUrl>https://image-us.samsung.com/SamsungUS/home/televisions-and-home-theater/tvs/qled-tvs/pdp/q80t-series/feature-benefits/14-Feature_2020_QLED_Smart_Hub_One_Remote_Control_US_PC.jpg</imageUrl>
         <legalDescription>* Remote color and design may vary by model.<i>
               <br/>
               <br/>
            </i>
         </legalDescription>
         <subTitle>Samsung OneRemote*</subTitle>
         <title>OneRemote for total control</title>
         <videoType>bc</videoType>
      </features>
```

Desired Output:

```
<features>
         <desc>
The sleek and slim OneRemote automatically detects and controls all compatible connected devices and content.
         </desc>
         <imageUrl>https://image-us.samsung.com/SamsungUS/home/televisions-and-home-theater/tvs/qled-tvs/pdp/q80t-series/feature-benefits/14-Feature_2020_QLED_Smart_Hub_One_Remote_Control_US_PC.jpg</imageUrl>
         <legalDescription>* Remote color and design may vary by model.<i>
               <br/>
               <br/>
            </i>
         </legalDescription>
         <subTitle>Samsung OneRemote*</subTitle>
         <title>OneRemote for total control</title>
         <videoType>bc</videoType>
      </features>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using **Identity Transform** pattern.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span[@class='st']">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```